# Occurrence of string in array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to count the occurrences of each element in a given array. So far, I have managed to achieve this with the exception that it loops all elements and I need to output only those which are unique.

```
<?php

$array = array('b','b','a','a','b');

foreach ($array as $element) {

    $hold = implode(" ", $array);
    print $element. ' -> ' . substr_count($hold, $element) . '<br />';

}
```

Thus the output now is:

```
b -> 3
b -> 3
a -> 2
a -> 2
b -> 3
```

I want to remove the duplicate elements but if I do `array_unique()` before I `implode()` and subsequently make the count, I will get only one occurrence due to the fact that I have removed the repeating elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to do it for you.

```
$counts = array_count_values($array);

foreach ($counts as $match => $count) {
     echo "$match -> $count";
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would do. Quick question - how do I sort output ascending.

Comment: @user3788751: using `sort()`

Comment: How could I wrap `$match` with `sort()` when it's not an array?

Comment: @user3788751: you haven't told anything about `$match` but about `output`. What exactly do you want? Have you checked `ksort`?

Comment: As of the code supplied by @alex it outputs: `b -> 3 a -> 2` and I want it to be in ascending order like `a -> 2 b -> 3`

Comment: @user3788751: Have you checked `ksort`? (not sure why you have ignored this advice)